# How to access the files from a s3 storage using java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jar

I have created my vm in aws using ec2 instance. Also i have created a bucket in s3 storage and some folders in that bucket. I have my java jar file in filezilla and now i want to run my application. This scenario is working ok in the case when I have my filed I want to access in filezilla also but now that I want to create a s3 storage instance I do not know how can my java application can access these folders. Do I need to create a new java class in my application in order to access these folders from s3 storage?

I am not quite familiar with aws and I will appreciate any help from you guys.Even if you send me some useful links which solve my problem it will be a great help for me.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you check this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/java-sdk/latest/developer-guide/java-dg-roles.html

Comment: take a look at this sample: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UploadObjSingleOpJava.html